# RSpec can't see Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a RSpec specification:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'session_project' do
  before(:each) do
    @user = User.create(
        username: 'user',
        password: 'test',
        password_confirmation: 'test',
        email: 'user@example.com'
    )
    @project = Project.create(name: 'Project 1', active: true, user_id: @user.id)
  end
  context 'when I am on the project page for Project 1' do
    it 'knows the current project is Project 1' do
      pending
    end
  end
end
# and so on.
```

`User` and `Project` are models of course - I want to test that the current project is being saved to and cleared from the session at the right times. When I run RSpec, it complains:

```
Failure/Error: @user = User.create(
NameError:
uninitialized constant User
```

If I cut-and-paste the `User.create` into a rails console it creates the user just fine.

Previous people who have asked about similar problems just needed to add `require 'spec_helper'`, but I've already done that. So how do I make the Rails models available to RSpec?

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#default-helper-files

Comment: That's the one! Make that a comment and I can give you the kudos.

Comment: That *is* a comment ;)

Comment: But you knew what I meant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under RSpec 3.x you need the `rails_helper` if you want Rails classes loaded up.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#default-helper-files